# Fluency & FluentBuilder - create builder from another builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Assuming that my application has model and DTO classes:

- DinnerList
- DinnerListDTO

And for testing purposes I'm using Fluency and it's FluentBuilder, I have two builders:

- DinnerListBuilder
- DinnerListDTOBuilder

As I would like to test logic responsible for translating model into DTO, I'm creating instance of `DinnerList` using builder:

```
var dinnerList = new DinnerListBuilder().WithId(1).build();
```

and then I'm using DinnerListDTO builder to create the object that I would like have on the output, like that:

```
var outputDto = new DinnerListDTOBuilder().OpenUntil(dinnerList.OpenUntil)
                    .WithCateringName(dinnerList.Catering.Name)
                    .WithCateringUrl(dinnerList.Catering.Url)
                    .WithId(dinnerList.Id)
                    .WithOwnerName(dinnerList.Owner.Name)
                    .build();
```

So basically I'm using `DinnerListDTOBuilder` to build my expected result object, by using values from the source (model) object that has been built already.

Is there a better way of doing it? I have came up with something like this:

```
public class DinnerListDTOBuilder : FluentBuilder<DinnerListDTO>
    {
        ...
        public DinnerListDTOBuilder FromDinnerList(DinnerList dinnerList)
        {
            return OpenUntil(dinnerList.OpenUntil)
               .WithCateringName(dinnerList.Catering.Name)
               .WithCateringUrl(dinnerList.Catering.Url)
               .WithId(dinnerList.Id)
               .WithOwnerName(dinnerList.Owner?.Name);
        }

        public DinnerListDTOBuilder FromDinnerList(FluentBuilder<DinnerList> builder)
        {
            return FromDinnerList(builder.build());
        }
}
```

Which then in the test looks like that:

```
...
var outputDto = new DinnerListDTOBuilder().FromDinnerList(dinnerList).build();
...
```

So it makes the code more readable. My question is whether there is a better way to setup such mapping? Especially when I'd like to build one object from another builder, like in this method:

```
        public DinnerListDTOBuilder FromDinnerList(FluentBuilder<DinnerList> builder)
        {
            return FromDinnerList(builder.build());
        }
```